# WSL how to reset and recover original configuration files

Tags: bash, bashrc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I tried to modify the color settings on the bash console in WSL Ubuntu. I have tried editing .bashrc and playing with the defaults and properties settings. I can no longer set the colors and so need to reset WSL.
I have tried turning it off and back on but saves my current settings somewhere.

How can I revert to the original settings?

Comment: For `.bashrc` specifically, you should be able to copy an unmodified version from the `/etc/skel` directory

Comment: Thanks !! I wish I had known, I ended up disabling WSL, removing all the local files in appdata and then re-installing.